# How to make TFS detect changes in folders outside solution?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-2015, tfvc

I'm making an angular webapp for a C# solution and I have to use TFS.

I set my workspace as `local` (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38200431/1538384)) and added the angular folder from Source Control Explorer.

Now all existing files are marked with the `[add]` tag and I can check-in them, but I can't understand why added or removed files are not detected as pending changes.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

They're under "Excluded" changes. You'll see a marker that says "Detected: X adds" or "Y removes". You can click it to promote them to tracked changes. It assumes that stuff that's being added or removed outside of Visual Studio isn't intended to be in source control, so it doesn't start tracking until you tell it that you want them to be tracked.

Comment: but it detects all the .js, .js.map and all the node_modules files!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the perfect solution you're looking for, but I ran into an almost identical issue.  This is how I solved it,

**1)** Open Solution Explorer in Visual Studio

**2)** Find your Project ( Angular Project )

**3)** Right click on it, and click Compare changes.

**4)** In compare options see View Options and check the following:

- Show items that exist only in source path
- Show items that exist only in target path
- Show items that are different

**5)** Then find all the files that are in your local mapping that are missing from your server version, right click on them and click "Add file".  You should be able to do this for entire folders / groups of files using shift + click .

**6)** Once you've added all your missing files, make sure they're being tracked in Team Explorer -> Pending changes, then check in your files.

I haven't figured out how to get Visual Studio to track these files automatically as I believe it requires a solution file like in normal C# projects to track them, but I could be wrong.